# Similar blocks of code found in 2 location in IF ELSE statement. Consider refactoring JS

Tags: javascript, refactoring

```js
if (notesValue) {
  document.querySelector(`.card-${domain.id} .add-notes-button`).classList.add('notes-filled');
} else {
  document.querySelector(`.card-${domain.id} .add-notes-button`).classList.remove('notes-filled');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The refactoring is simply done by using the second *force* param of the `toggle` Method:

> `Element.classList.toggle("className", forceBoolean)`
> [MDN Docs DOMTokenList.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle)

```js
const EL_button = document.querySelector(`.card-${domain.id} .add-notes-button`);
EL_button.classList.toggle('notes-filled', notesValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document
 .querySelector(`.card-${domain.id} .add-notes-button`)
 .classList
 .toggle('notes-filled', notesValue);
```

Comment: Hey, consider explaining why this code solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Using toggle is a good idea but for a more general case where a method like that doesn't exist you could choose which method on the object to target e.g.:

```
document.querySelector(`.card-${domain.id} .add-notes-button`)
  .classList[notesValue ? 'add' : 'remove']('notes-filled');
```